# Multiple Admin URL's

Tags: admin, url

Currently I have two stores on my Magento installation with each of them having their own url.

SiteA.com -> SiteA.com

SiteB.com -> SiteB.com

However the admin section does not work this way. After the administrator logs in, the url switches to SiteA.com (see below).

SiteA.com/admin -> SiteA.com/admin

SiteB.com/admin -> SiteA.com/admin

My question is if I can get the admin URL to stay on the same domain like below. I am not worried about restricting information to each domain. I am only concerned about keeping the domain the same once logged in.

SiteA.com/admin -> SiteA.com/admin

SiteB.com/admin -> SiteB.com/admin

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Since the admin is it's own "store" it needs a base domain, the one set on `global`.